# Use S3 AmazonS3Client listObjects prefix with wildcard?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Does the AWS S3 AmazonS3Client.listObjects (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html) support wildcard?
for example, can one do the following:

```
ListObjectsRequest listObjectsRequest = new ListObjectsRequest().
withBucketName("foo").
withPrefix("*/dt=2013-03-28/*").
withDelimiter("/");
```

Answer (score 7):

No, you cannot. In fact, `*` is a valid character in a key name in S3. For example, a key like `/foo/b*ar/dt=2013-03-28/abc.xml` is valid.
You will either need to reorganize your keys according to a common prefix or iterate over them all.

PS: depending on your use case, it is possible that you can use a [`marker`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/ListObjectsRequest.html#withMarker%28java.lang.String%29).