# apache camel s3 component - specify suffix / regex on prefix

Tags: regex, amazon-s3, apache-camel

I'm using the aws s3 component of Apache Camel.  And I want to consume specific data only with an extension of .txt, how can this be achieved?  According to camel documentation, it has a prefix options which is not suitable in my case since i want to filter based on extensions.

TIA

Comment: This seems not to be possible. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16220954/use-s3-amazons3client-listobjects-prefix-with-wildcard. Perhaps a s3 optimization thing.

Answer (score 2):

No there is no way to do this.

You cannot use a regular expression in the prefix option as it is just a string, see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/ListObjectsRequest.html#setPrefix(java.lang.String)

The only way would be to retrieve a list of the files and filter them. Or name the files in such a way so that you can use a prefix

Comment: I'm setting the deleteAfterRead option to true, so when I consumed the file and will just apply the filter after consuming, the file would be by then deleted on the bucket.

Comment: You'll have to set the option to false then :)

Comment: I need to set it to true; otherwise, it will be fetched by camel again. long as file/s is/are in the bucket, it will be retrieved.